# Terraform: How to use iam_policy without locking yourself out

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-iam

I'm having issues with using `iam_policy` resource types without being getting myself locked-out on `terraform destroy`. This applies to resource types like `google_storage_bucket_iam_policy` and `google_project_iam_policy`.

This example applies to `google_storage_bucket_iam_policy` resource. Let's say I have a list of owners and the service account used by terraform to be granted the `roles/storage.admin` role.

```
resource "google_storage_bucket" "default" {
  name = "default"
  location = "EU"
}

resource "google_storage_bucket_iam_role"  "owners" {
  bucket = "default"
  binding {
    role = "roles/storage.admin"
    members = [
      "${var.owners}",
      "${var.serviceAccount}"
    ]
  }
}
```

The order of the resource creation is bucket first, then policy. Naturally, the `destroy` action processes the resources in reverse order - policy first, then bucket. However after policy removal, the service account doesn't have sufficient privileges for the bucket removal.

Perhaps a way around could be using `google_storage_bucket_iam_member` resource for the owners, however this approach doesn't seem very clean as it inherits whatever was defined on the project previously, which could be quite messy.

Btw, the same logic applies on the project level to the resource `google_project_iam_policy`. Thanks in advance.

Comment: In case anyone locks themselves out of a project: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72524593/2961387

Answer (score 2):

You can create an explicit dependency which will:

1. Ensure the IAM role is created before the bucket
2. Ensure the bucket is destroyed before the IAM role

Here is your example with a `depends_on` added:

```
resource "google_storage_bucket" "default" {
  name = "default"
  location = "EU"
  depends_on = ["google_storage_bucket_iam_role.owners"]
}

resource "google_storage_bucket_iam_role"  "owners" {
  bucket = "default"
  binding {
    role = "roles/storage.admin"
    members = [
      "${var.owners}",
      "${var.serviceAccount}"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this suggestion fails due to cyclic dependency.

`Error: Error asking for user input: 1 error(s) occurred:

* Cycle: google_storage_bucket_iam_role.owners, google_storage_bucket.default`