# GCP - terraform removed all policies, how can I revert

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-cloud-iam

I run following terraform. I made a mistake of using `google_storage_bucket_iam_policy` instead of `google_storage_bucket_iam_binding` so instead of adding new policy, it replaced all of existing policy.

```
data "google_iam_policy" "deploy-script-admin-policy" {
  binding {
    role = "roles/storage.objectAdmin"
    members = [
      "serviceAccount:${google_service_account.deploy-script.email}",
    ]
  }
}
# deploy script can read/write to a bucket
resource "google_storage_bucket_iam_policy" "policy" {
  bucket      = "my-bucket"
  policy_data = data.google_iam_policy.deploy-script-admin-policy.policy_data
}
```

Now I cannot run terraform plan because I lost access to my own bucket. I get error message like `<my email> does not have storage.buckets.get access to the Google Cloud Storage bucket., forbidden`.

I went to GCP console and tried to either delete or update permission of this bucket but it won't work either since bucket permission doesn't allow it (I have owner and storage.admin role).

How can I recover from this situation? I don't mind deleting the bucket if that's the only option.

**EDIT**:
I don't know what happened, but maybe GCP has some way of auto-recover from such situation. For some reason I was able to edit bucket again from console after a while...

Comment: You cannot. because this operation is an authoritative operation. Hence its advised to save current configuration and then build on top of it

Answer (score 4):

###### *undo*, *revert*, or *roll-back*, an *overwritten*, *changed*, or *deleted* project iam policy

Firstly, yes, you can essentially "revert" or "undo" GCP IAM project policy updates. I provide the method down below. But, this is a tricky situation, so I'd advise anyone take a careful approach here, and first understand what's happening.

Now, you've mistakenly or thought it'd be fine to either fully or partially overwrite your project's IAM policy - which to me only seems possible through accident with an automated infrastructure as code (Iac) pipeline provisioning – i.e., using Terraform or similar.

##### How this happens

The underlying GCP API method IaC tools will use is `projects.setIamPolicy`. Which even Terraform documents plenty of warnings and explicitly only echo's the guard-railing the API as a GCP responsibility - ultimately preserving terraform's opinionated approach to provision *any* resource without nuance (imo a tough proposition that counters the state and holistic ability of automated IaC).

> `projects.setIamPolicy` has a lot of constraints which are documented [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bT8wM.jpg). In addition to these constraints, IAM Conditions cannot be used with Basic Roles such as Owner. Violating these constraints will result in the API returning 400 error code so please review these if you encounter errors with this resource.

Well, unfortunately most of the world probably enables their Terraform provisioning in an automated fashion with service accounts that aren't bound to these constraints, thus the constraints don't matter if terraform can provision any resource, like the full GCP Project IAM policy:

> **google_project_iam_policy**: `Authoritative`. Sets the IAM policy for the project and replaces any existing policy already attached.

I think `Authoritative` is just documentation labeling. Nevertheless, terraform resource naming convention is not clear, and a lot of engineers will likely assuming their *"simple & narrow IaC policy update won't hurt a fly."*

Which the big red Terraform warning doesn't really alleviate with current wording.

|  |
| --- |
| [image] |

It does however provide part of the answer. (You need org access or support from someone who has it).

##### Addressing a serious Project IAM Policy mistake

###### 1. Reestablish access

Get an `organization` administrator to either conduct the next steps, or re-add a sr cloud engineer on the project, with an `owner` role on the project. I don't advise given org rights to any project memember's to fix a project's problem.

###### 2. Audit the situation

Amazing cloud service: [GCP Asset Inventory](https://cloud.google.com/asset-inventory/docs) which also gives you a great [way to view asset history](https://cloud.google.com/asset-inventory/docs/viewing-asset-history)

There's a tab to select IAM Policies, and the top listed policy should be the project's `IAM POLICY`. click that, and within the right side panel you want to select the `CHANGE HISTORY` tab.

Now, find the change (you should know the cause, but in this view find the actual breaking point, so you can get a hold of the preview metadata/policy-json.

| just an example screen, yours will look different which much of a change diff style |
| --- |
| [image] |

###### 3. Copy the json before the breaking change

i.e. the previous/stable state of your project

###### 4. Copy the most current IAM policy json's `etag`

basically a hash of current/bad state.

###### 5. Revert by using the GCP API (make sure you have access on the recreated/reestablished user in the project)

First, edit the previous/good state json down to an applicable format (you'll remove ancestor tags and some others, keep the [key schema aspects](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/reference/rest/v1/Policy).

```
# the basic schema you need to preserve with copied json
# paste previous_policy json in new json (local, cloud shell, etc)
------------------------------------------------------------------
{
  "auditConfig":[...]
  "bindings": [...],
  "etag": "..." #<--- copy this from the current bad state,
}
```

Use the set-iam-policy command

```
## Update the new policy
# know what the command does
gcloud projects set-iam-policy --command 

# fire away
gcloud projects set-iam-policy MyBrokenProjectName previous_policy.json
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't revert changes made and restore your access to the bucket in question.

`[google_storage_bucket_iam_policy][1]` is authoritative (as @Prashant mentioned) which means that first, it erases any policies for the object and then creates the ones that you defined.

If your definition didn't include proper access and you got yourself locked then the only solution is to delete the bucket.

Comment: hm as I wrote in the original post I wasn't even able to delete. Then for some reason my change got reverted after say 30min and I can now edit them again.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Project IAM Admin or some other role that enables you to edit IAM permissions, you can run `terraform destroy` on your `google_storage_bucket_iam_policy.policy` resource and that should restore the permissions to be permissions inherited from the project IAM permissions. This means that if you have the Storage Admin permission, you should be able to modify the bucket permissions again.